# Nodejs variable and string in variable?

Tags: node.js

I am new in nodejs, how can I concatenate variables and string in variable?
I want to get a product price. Firestore stored car and carprice.
I get car price from Firestore: doc.data().carprice

But the client not send me "carprice", client send me "product1" variable: "car".

So I have:

product1 = car

I need:

const price = doc.data().product1"price"

This should look like this:

const price = doc.data().carprice

How can I do it?
Thanks!:))

Comment: Too lazy to find the duplicate for this so I'm just going to leave the answer as a comment: `doc.data()[product1 + "price"]`

Comment: In javascript `foo.carprice` is the same as `foo["carprice"]`

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

There is a really convenient notation for string creation in node

```js
const result = `${Variable1} any text ${Object1.property}`
```